# I am getting "vector subscript out of range" error

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, assertion

I am writing a program for reading some numbers from txt files and saving them into matrices with c++. But i am not that familiar with matrix concept and a little confused. When i try to run the program i get vector subscription out of range error and i don't know what to do if someone would look at my code and show me the right way it would be great.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "strutils.h"
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void Print(const vector<vector<int>> & mat)
{
for (int j=0; j < mat.size(); j++)
{   
    for (int k=0; k < mat[0].size(); k++)
    {   
        cout << mat[j][k];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
}


int main()
{
string filename;
int countRow = 0, countCol = 0, emptyCount = 0;
cout << "Please enter the input file name: ";
cin >> filename;

ifstream input;
input.open(filename);

while(input.fail())
{
    cout<< "Could not open the file please enter the correct file name:";
    cin >> filename ;
    input.open(filename);
}

while(!input.eof())
{
    string s;
    int num;
    while (getline(input, s))
    {
        countRow++;
        vector<vector<int>> mat(countRow, vector<int>(countCol));
        istringstream input(s);
        while (input >> num)
        {
            countCol++;
            emptyCount++;
            vector <int> row(countCol);
            mat.push_back(row);
            mat [(countRow - 1)] [(countCol - 1)] = num;
        }
        countCol = 0;

    }


}
vector<vector<int>> mat(countRow, vector<int>(emptyCount/countRow));
Print(mat);

cin.get();
cin.ignore();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't rely in `mat[0]`'s size to figure out the sizes of the other vectors. They might be smaller/bigger.

Comment: @Nick from the construction of `mat`, that doesn't look like the problem.  Still a good suggestion in general though.

Comment: Did you already debug your program to see where the error occurs? Please do that first, before asking people here do do this for you!

Comment: Why the outer loop on the input?

Comment: And why all the vectors constructed in the loop, which won't outlive the loop.

Comment: @Nick In general, you're right, but in this case, he's printing the vector he constructed with `std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat( countRow, std::vector<int>( emptyCount / countRow );`.  Which will have all of the nested vectors with the same size (and which will contain `0` everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to begin.  You're creating lots of temporary
vectors, which you never use; then you output a vector
constructed without any of the data you read.  You're counting
the rows and lines, although the vectors themselves will do this
for you.  And as @Nick points out, you've got a `mat[countRow
- 1][countCol - 1]` where `countCol` is guaranteed to be larger
than the vector it's indexing into.  What's wrong with the
following for your read loop:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat;
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
    mat.push_back( std::vector<int>() );
    std::istringstream input( line ):
    int num;
    while ( input >> num ) {
        mat.back().push_back( num );
    }
}
```

Let `std::vector` keep track of the size.  Don't create a new
vector each time in the inner loop.  And only create a nested
one (the one you push back) in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the second for loop you should check against mat[j] and not always the first element.

```
for (int k=0; k < mat[j].size(); k++)
```